How to combine multiple XSD schema files into one XSD schema file
I'm trying to import data from XML to SQL. Here we have around 10 xmls with different schemas. I'm using SSIS to import data from XML to SQL. But here I need to generate 10 XSD schema files for each one.
Instead of that how can I combine all these XML/XSD files into one schema file. So need to refer only one XSD source in SSIS.
Any idea to do this. Or is there any python or c# code to make this possible ?

You don't usually combine.  Instead you add an include : https://www.w3schools.com/xml/el_include.asp

You are out of luck here. Each differently structured XML needs its own separate XML Schema (XSD) in SSIS. Your solution would be to use a single  SSIS XML Task, operation Validation, and use expressions to dynamically control XML/XSD pairs.

If two schema documents have the same targetNamespace then you can generally combine them by copy/paste, though using xs:include usually makes more sense.
If they have different target namespaces, then they have to remain separate: you can build a composite schema by writing a "root" schema that just does xs:import on all the relevant schema documents.
